# Cannot see the object constructor on the client side

Tags: wcf, f#

I have a type:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Item(id : string, name : string) = 
    [<DataMember>]
    member val ItemId = id with get, set
    [<DataMember>]
    member val ItemName = name with get, set

    new() = new Item("", "")
```

Service contract:

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type ISimpleService =
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract InsertItem: b:Item -> unit
```

And service:

```
type SimpleService() =
    interface ISimpleService with
        member x.InsertItem item = 
            let sql = new SqlConnector()
            sql.InsertItem(item)  
            ()
```

On the client side I can create Item and pass it to the service:

```
let newItem = new webService.ServiceTypes.Entities.Item()
newItem.ItemId <- "10"
newItem.ItemName <- "ten"
client.InsertItem(newItem)
```

But I don't have constructor which takes two parameters, so I can not do something like this:

```
let newItem = new webService.ServiceTypes.Entities.Item("10", "one")
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Constructor's are not carried with Data Contracts.  Data Contracts are more of an SOA item, whereas a constructor is more of an OOP item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCF you transfer data by serialization (from your wsdl blueprint) - you are not passing object references. If you want to have constructors on the client side you can always make a class that extends the proxy class from the service.